# What are the Components of drag force in spherical polar coordinates?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, coordinate-systems, drag

How to decompose the drag force in three components of spherical polar coordinates?

Since
$ F =\frac{1}{2}\rho C A v^2 $

or in vector form :

$\vec F = \vert F\vert \hat F = \frac{1}{2}\rho C A v^2 \hat v = \frac{1}{2}\rho C A v^2 \frac {\hat v}{\vert {\vec v}\vert} = \frac{1}{2}\rho C A v \hat v$

$\dot{r}= \vec v$ = $r\hat{r}$ + $r\dot{\phi}\hat{\theta}$ + $r\dot{\phi}\sin{\theta}\hat{\phi}, $ in spherical polar coordinates 
$v^2$ = $r^2 + r^2{\dot{\theta}^2}+ r^2\dot{\phi}\sin^2{\theta}$

can one write $ F_\theta =\frac{1}{2}\rho C A (r^2{\dot{\theta}^2}) ? $ ; $ F_\phi =\frac{1}{2}\rho C A (r^2\dot{\phi}\sin^2{\theta}) ? $

For a particle are moving along the azimuthal direction through the plasma is the force $ F = F_\phi =\frac{1}{2}\rho C A (r^2\dot{\phi}\sin^2{\theta}) ? $

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Q1**: The formula given for $F$ is not a vector equation, so I don't think I can get vector components out of it.

**Q2**: Note that $v^2=\mathbf{v}\cdot\mathbf{v}$, and use $\hat{\mathbf{r}}\cdot \hat{\mathbf{r}} = \hat{\boldsymbol{\theta}}\cdot \hat{\boldsymbol{\theta}} = \hat{\boldsymbol{\phi}}\cdot \hat{\boldsymbol{\phi}} = 1$ in the conventional spherical coordinate system. This means that $$v^2=\dot r^2+r^2\dot\theta^2+r^2\dot\phi ^2\sin^2\theta.$$

**Q3**: Motion in the azimuthal direction fixes $r=R$ and $\theta = \theta_0$, so we have $$v^2=R^2\dot\phi ^2\sin^2\theta_0, $$ which makes perfect geometrical sense. Just think of a particle constrained to move at constant latitude on a sphere.

**Note**: $\phi$ here denotes the azimuthal angle and $\theta$ the polar angle. The line element is $$d\mathbf{s} = dr\:\hat{\mathbf{r}} + r\:d\theta\:\hat{\boldsymbol{\theta}} + r\sin \theta \:d\phi \:\hat{\boldsymbol{\phi}} $$

Comment: Thank you for your response. Almost in all papers they always gives the scalar expression but not the vector form.

Comment: What would be the components of the forces along R, theta and phi?

Comment: Like I said in my answer to Q1, that entirely depends on the direction of velocity. I can't give you components to a scalar quantity because that doesn't make sense

Comment: However drag should point  opposite to velocity. So the velocity unit vector will give you direction of the force, and now you can figure the components out

Comment: The reason I asked is to be able to find the drag/force for a particle moving along any direction. For instance, the plasma is at the origin of a Spherical polar Frame and pass through it at some radial distance, at ang co-latitude angle (theta) = 45degree and azimulth angle (phi) 45degree. How would I incorporate it in the drag equation?